# Requirejs paths getting overwritten intermittently

Tags: requirejs

I have configured paths for handlebars and underscore in Requirejs config like so:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl:          '/js/',
  paths: {

    /* Core Libraries */

    underscore :      'libs/underscore/underscore-min',
    backbone :        'libs/backbone/backbone-min',
    handlebars:       'libs/handlebars/handlebars.min'
  }
```

This is how I initialize requirejs:

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="/js/main" src="/js/libs/require/require.js"></script>
```

When i refresh the page multiple times, I get an error message saying: 
Uncaught Error: Script error for "handlebars".
Digging a little deeper, I could see in the network tab of Chrome Dev tools that it's basically a 404 not found for the modules:
404 Not Found - http://localhost:8888/js/underscore.js
The above path is not the one configured in require.config.
I'm not able to exactly pinpoint the issue as this occurs only intermittently. 
Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question to show your `script` elements and show how you kick off the loading of your application.

Answer (score -1):

Backbone.js needs underscore.js so if you refresh the page multiple times the libraries may not be loaded with the correct order
Please try shim configuration as below;

```
require.config({
   baseUrl:'js',
   paths: {

   /* Core Libraries */

   underscore :      'libs/underscore/underscore-min',
   backbone :        'libs/backbone/backbone-min',
   handlebars:       'libs/handlebars/handlebars.min'
  },
  shim:{
   'backbone': {
     deps: ['underscore']
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Backbone calls `define(['underscore', 'jquery', 'exports'], function(_, $, exports)`, so the dependency is already there.

Comment: define(['underscore'  means trying to find it under baseUrl  like js/underscore.js  ? @Louis

Comment: Yes.The array is the list of modules that Backbone depends on.